# Why is this implementation of async WebRequests slower than the synchronous implementation?

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, async-await

I have an application that requires many requests to a third party REST service.  I thought that modifying this part of the application to make the requests asynchronously would potentially speed things up, so I wrote a POC console application to test things out.

To my surprise the async code takes almost twice as long to complete as the synchronous version.  Am I just doing it wrong?

```
async static void LoadUrlsAsync() 
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsAsync Start - {0}", startTime);


    var numberOfRequest = 3;
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequest; i++)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";

        var task = LoadUrlAsync(request);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    var stopTime = DateTime.Now;
    var duration = (stopTime - startTime);
    Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsAsync Complete - {0}", stopTime);
    Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsAsync Duration - {0}ms", duration);
}

async static Task<string> LoadUrlAsync(WebRequest request)
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        value = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - Bytes: {1}", request.RequestUri, value.Length);
    }

    return value;
}
```

NOTE:
I have also tried setting the **maxconnections=100** in the app.config in an attempt to eliminate throttling from the system.net connection pool.  This setting doesn't seem to make an impact on the performance.

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: If this is a benchmark I would not try to connect to Google or any other public/commercial site. Maybe they detect so many accesses to the same URL as an attempt of DoS and it is them who slow you down. Can't you test it against your own server?

Comment: The synchronous version of this code simply uses "request.GetResponse", removes use of the "Task.WhenAll(tasks)" and removes the "async" prefixes from the methods.

Comment: As the bottom line, if you are writting a benchmark, try to control *everything* that can affect the results.

Comment: I have an internal API that I am accessing. For the purposes of the question on stackoverflow, I modified the URL to something everyone can access.  The behavior of the code is the same regardless of the URL.  I am simply trying to determine if I have a problem with the way I have authored the async code.  Something that may be causing a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async version becomes faster as you increase the number of threads. I'm not certain, however my guess is that you are bypassing the cost of setting up the threads. When you pass this threshold the async version becomes superior. Try 50 or even 500 requests and you should see async is faster.  That's how it worked out for me.

```
500 Async Requests:  11.133 seconds
500 Sync Requests:   18.136 seconds
```

If you only have ~3 calls then I suggest avoiding async.  Here's what I used to test:

```
public class SeperateClass
{
    static int numberOfRequest = 500;
    public async static void LoadUrlsAsync()
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsAsync Start - {0}", startTime);

        var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequest; i++)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png") as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";

            var task = LoadUrlAsync(request);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var stopTime = DateTime.Now;
        var duration = (stopTime - startTime);
        Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsAsync Complete - {0}", stopTime);
        Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsAsync Duration - {0}ms", duration);
    }

    async static Task<string> LoadUrlAsync(WebRequest request)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            value = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - Bytes: {1}", request.RequestUri, value.Length);
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class SeperateClassSync
{
    static int numberOfRequest = 500;
    public async static void LoadUrlsSync()
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsSync Start - {0}", startTime);

        var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequest; i++)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png") as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";

            var task = LoadUrlSync(request);
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var stopTime = DateTime.Now;
        var duration = (stopTime - startTime);
        Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsSync Complete - {0}", stopTime);
        Console.WriteLine("LoadUrlsSync Duration - {0}ms", duration);
    }

    async static Task<string> LoadUrlSync(WebRequest request)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())//Still async FW, just changed to Sync call here
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            value = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - Bytes: {1}", request.RequestUri, value.Length);
        }

        return value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SeperateClass.LoadUrlsAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();//record result and run again

        SeperateClassSync.LoadUrlsSync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: While there is an overhead in setting up the tasks/threads (microseconds/milliseconds), this is negligible regarding the magnitude of time the downloads require (seconds/minutes) and should barely influence the measurements. As pointed out in another comment to this questions, it is more likely that one of the key factors is multiple server accesses at once (which might trigger throttling...)

Comment: @elgonzo - How does that explain my results?

Comment: P.Brian - Did you actually run the code in the question, or did you have similar code of your own?  I may have to wait and try this on my home Internet connection, but I'm consistently seeing the async code running nearly twice as long as the synchronous version.  I have also tried repeating the request 50 times, with the async code still taking twice as long.

Comment: @JohnGully - I dropped the code you posted.  I updated the post with the exact code for both tests.

Comment: @P_BrianMackey - Thanks for the update.  Once I saw your metrics I realized how slow my results actually were.  I managed to get my code moved out onto another machine in the cloud.  I am now seeing 100 async requests in 12 sec and 100 sync requests in 15 sec.

Answer (score 5):

First, try to avoid microbenchmarking. When the differences of your code timings are swamped by network conditions, your results lose meaning.

That said, you should set [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) to `int.MaxValue`. Also, use end-to-end `async` methods (i.e., `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync`) - or even better, use `HttpClient`, which was designed for `async` HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests it's faster to use the `WebRequest.GetResponseAsync()` method for 3 parallel requests.

It should be more noticeable with large requests, many requests (3 is not many), and requests from different websites.

What are the exact results you are getting?  In your question you are converting a TimeSpan to a string and calling it milliseconds but you aren't actually calculating the milliseconds.  It's displaying the standard TimeSpan.ToString which will show fractions of a second.

Comment: I have typically been attempting 3 - 5 calls.  3 calls is taking around 17 seconds to complete in the async implementation, and about 11 seconds synchronously.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the problem was more of an environmental issue than anything else.  Once I moved the code to another machine on a different network, the results were much more inline with my expectations.

The original async code does in fact execute more quickly than the synchronous version.  This helps me ensure that I am not introducing additional complexity to our application without the expected performance gains.